# Jquery Div Element Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have a div (main div) which contains several div elements(sub divs). I want to hide all inside div elements using Jquery. Can any body help me. But main div should display always.

Comment: The jQuery docs are really good - you should check them out http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be easy as:

```
$('#mainDiv > div').hide();
```

to hide only all direct children from `#mainDiv` or

```
$('#mainDiv div').hide();
```

to hide any descendant div of  `#mainDiv`.

Answer (score 0):

and also you can animate the hiding like this:

```
$('#mainDiv div').slideUp();
$('#mainDiv div').slideToggle();
$('#mainDiv div').fadeToggle();
```

these are simple jquery animations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,works fine

```
<div style="text-align:center;background-color: lightblue;">Main div
<button id="checkButton"type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
<div id="subdiv1" hidden>Sub Div 1</div>
<div id="subdiv2" hidden>Sub Div 2</div>
<div id="subdiv3" hidden>Sub Div 3</div>
<div id="subdiv4" hidden>Sub Div 4</div>
<div id="subdiv5" hidden>Sub Div 5</div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#checkButton").click(function(){
$("#subdiv1").toggle();
$("#subdiv2").toggle();
$("#subdiv3").toggle();
$("#subdiv4").toggle();
$("#subdiv5").toggle();
});
});
</script>
```